# Call to a member function get_error_messages() on null

Tags: plugins, fatal-error

I am using  the following code for submit custom post by users in a custom page. When i submit form i get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_error_messages() on null in D:\Ampps\www\wordpress2\wp-content\themes\tours\includes\add_tour.func.php on line 85

Line 85:

> ...} elseif (count($reg_errors->get_error_messages()) < 1) {...

```
    <?php

$postTitleError = '';

if(isset($_POST['submitted']) && isset($_POST['post_nonce_field']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['post_nonce_field'], 'post_nonce')) {

        validate_tour_data(
            $_POST['tourTitle'],$_POST['keywords'],$_POST['sourceTour'],$_POST['destinationTour'],$_POST['duration'],$_POST['tourContent'],$_POST['agancyservice'],$_POST['passports'],$_POST['transport'],$_POST['hotel_name'],$_POST['hotelRate'],$_POST['room1'],$_POST['room2'],$_POST['room3'],$_POST['room4'],$_POST['desc']
        );
        global $tourTitle,$keywords,$sourceTour,$destinationTour,$duration,$tourContent,$agancyservice,$passports,$transport,$hotel_name,$hotelRate,$room1,$room2,$room3,$room4,$desc;

        $tourTitle = sanitize_text_field($_POST['tourTitle']);
        $keywords = sanitize_text_field($_POST['keywords']);
        $sourceTour = sanitize_text_field($_POST['sourceTour']);
        $destinationTour = sanitize_text_field($_POST['destinationTour']);
        $duration = sanitize_text_field($_POST['duration']);
        $tourContent = sanitize_text_field($_POST['tourContent']);
        $agancyservice = sanitize_text_field($_POST['agancyservice']);
        $passports = sanitize_text_field($_POST['passports']);
        $transport = sanitize_text_field($_POST['transport']);
        $hotel_name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['hotel_name']);
        $hotelRate = sanitize_text_field($_POST['hotelRate']);
        $room1 = sanitize_text_field($_POST['room1']);
        $room2 = sanitize_text_field($_POST['room2']);
        $room3 = sanitize_text_field($_POST['room3']);
        $room4 = sanitize_text_field($_POST['room4']);
        $desc = sanitize_text_field($_POST['desc']);
        add_complete_tour();
}

function validate_tour_data($tourTitle,$keywords,$sourceTour,$destinationTour,$duration,$tourContent,$agancyservice,$passports,$transport,$hotel_name,$hotelRate,$room1,$room2,$room3,$room4,$desc){
    global $reg_errors;
    $reg_errors = new WP_Error;

    if (empty($tourTitle)) {
        $reg_errors->add('tourTitle', 'عنوان تور را وارد کنید.');
    }

    if (empty($keywords)) {
        $reg_errors->add('keywords', 'حداقل یک کلمه کلیدی و حداکثر سه کلمه کلیدی وارد کنید.');
    }

    if (empty($sourceTour)) {
        $reg_errors->add('sourceTour', 'مبدا و آغاز تور را وارد کنید.');
    }

    if (empty($destinationTour)) {
        $reg_errors->add('destinationTour', 'مقصد تور را وارد کنید.');
    }

    if (empty($duration)) {
        $reg_errors->add('duration', 'مدت اقامت را وارد کنید.');
    }

    if (!is_numeric($duration)) {
        $reg_errors->add('duration', 'مدت اقامت فقط میتواند مقداری عددی باشد.');
    }

    if (empty($tourContent)) {
        $reg_errors->add('tourContent', 'توضیح مختصری در مورد تور وارد کنید.');
    }

    if (empty($agancyservice)) {
        $reg_errors->add('agancyservice', 'خدمات آژانس مسافرتی را وارد کنید.');
    }

    if (empty($passports)) {
        $reg_errors->add('passports', 'مدارک مورد نیاز تور مسافرنی را وارد کنید.');
    }

    if (empty($transport)) {
        $reg_errors->add('transport', 'نوع سفر را انتخاب کنید.');
    }
}

function add_complete_tour(){
    global $tourTitle,$keywords,$sourceTour,$destinationTour,$duration,$tourContent,$agancyservice,$passports,$transport,$hotel_name,$hotelRate,$room1,$room2,$room3,$room4,$desc;
    if (is_wp_error($reg_errors) && count($reg_errors->get_error_messages()) > 0) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="margin-top: 10px;font-size:15px;">';
        foreach ($reg_errors->get_error_messages() as $error) {
            echo '<strong>خطا</strong>:';
            echo $error . '<br/>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    } elseif (count($reg_errors->get_error_messages()) < 1) {

        $post_data = array(
          'post_title'    => $tourTitle,
          'post_content'  => $tourContent,
          'post_status'   => 'pending',
          'post_author'   => get_current_user_id(),
        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="margin-top: 10px;font-size:15px;">تور مسافرتی با موفقیت ثبت شد. پس از بررسی مدیریت و تایید منتشر خواهد شد.</div>';
    }     
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is right there in your error. Your first `if` checks that `$reg_errors` is definitely an instance of `WP_Error`, but your `elseif` doesn't. You need:

```
elseif ( is_wp_error( $reg_errors ) && count( $reg_errors->get_error_messages() ) < 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the prolem and resolved it. I edited the following:

```
add_complete_tour($tourTitle,$keywords,$sourceTour,$destinationTour,$duration,$tourContent,$agancyservice,$passports,$transport,$hotel_name,$hotelRate,$room1,$room2,$room3,$room4,$desc);
```

And added `$reg_errors` to global variable in `add_complete_tour function`:

```
    global $reg_errors,$tourTitle,$keywords,$sourceTour,$destinationTour,$duration,$tourContent,$agancyservice,$passports,$transport,$hotel_name,$hotelRate,$room1,$room2,$room3,$room4,$desc;
```

Complete code:

```
    <?php

$postTitleError = '';

if(isset($_POST['submitted']) && isset($_POST['post_nonce_field']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['post_nonce_field'], 'post_nonce')) {

        validate_tour_data(
            $_POST['tourTitle'],$_POST['keywords'],$_POST['sourceTour'],$_POST['destinationTour'],$_POST['duration'],$_POST['tourContent'],$_POST['agancyservice'],$_POST['passports'],$_POST['transport'],$_POST['hotel_name'],$_POST['hotelRate'],$_POST['room1'],$_POST['room2'],$_POST['room3'],$_POST['room4'],$_POST['desc']
        );
        global $tourTitle,$keywords,$sourceTour,$destinationTour,$duration,$tourContent,$agancyservice,$passports,$transport,$hotel_name,$hotelRate,$room1,$room2,$room3,$room4,$desc;

        $tourTitle = sanitize_text_field($_POST['tourTitle']);
        $keywords = sanitize_text_field($_POST['keywords']);
        $sourceTour = sanitize_text_field($_POST['sourceTour']);
        $destinationTour = sanitize_text_field($_POST['destinationTour']);
        $duration = sanitize_text_field($_POST['duration']);
        $tourContent = sanitize_text_field($_POST['tourContent']);
        $agancyservice = sanitize_text_field($_POST['agancyservice']);
        $passports = sanitize_text_field($_POST['passports']);
        $transport = sanitize_text_field($_POST['transport']);
        $hotel_name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['hotel_name']);
        $hotelRate = sanitize_text_field($_POST['hotelRate']);
        $room1 = sanitize_text_field($_POST['room1']);
        $room2 = sanitize_text_field($_POST['room2']);
        $room3 = sanitize_text_field($_POST['room3']);
        $room4 = sanitize_text_field($_POST['room4']);
        $desc = sanitize_text_field($_POST['desc']);
        add_complete_tour($tourTitle,$keywords,$sourceTour,$destinationTour,$duration,$tourContent,$agancyservice,$passports,$transport,$hotel_name,$hotelRate,$room1,$room2,$room3,$room4,$desc);
}

function validate_tour_data($tourTitle,$keywords,$sourceTour,$destinationTour,$duration,$tourContent,$agancyservice,$passports,$transport,$hotel_name,$hotelRate,$room1,$room2,$room3,$room4,$desc){
    global $reg_errors;
    $reg_errors = new WP_Error;
    if (empty($tourTitle)) {
        $reg_errors->add('tourTitle', 'عنوان تور را وارد کنید.');
    }

    if (empty($keywords)) {
        $reg_errors->add('keywords', 'حداقل یک کلمه کلیدی و حداکثر سه کلمه کلیدی وارد کنید.');
    }

    if (empty($sourceTour)) {
        $reg_errors->add('sourceTour', 'مبدا و آغاز تور را وارد کنید.');
    }

    if (empty($destinationTour)) {
        $reg_errors->add('destinationTour', 'مقصد تور را وارد کنید.');
    }

    if (empty($duration)) {
        $reg_errors->add('duration', 'مدت اقامت را وارد کنید.');
    }

    if (!is_numeric($duration)) {
        $reg_errors->add('duration', 'مدت اقامت فقط میتواند مقداری عددی باشد.');
    }

    if (empty($tourContent)) {
        $reg_errors->add('tourContent', 'توضیح مختصری در مورد تور وارد کنید.');
    }

    if (empty($agancyservice)) {
        $reg_errors->add('agancyservice', 'خدمات آژانس مسافرتی را وارد کنید.');
    }

    if (empty($passports)) {
        $reg_errors->add('passports', 'مدارک مورد نیاز تور مسافرنی را وارد کنید.');
    }

    if (empty($transport)) {
        $reg_errors->add('transport', 'نوع سفر را انتخاب کنید.');
    }
}

function add_complete_tour(){
    global $reg_errors,$tourTitle,$keywords,$sourceTour,$destinationTour,$duration,$tourContent,$agancyservice,$passports,$transport,$hotel_name,$hotelRate,$room1,$room2,$room3,$room4,$desc;

    if (is_wp_error($reg_errors) && count($reg_errors->get_error_messages()) > 0) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="margin-top: 10px;font-size:15px;">';
        foreach ($reg_errors->get_error_messages() as $error) {
            echo '<strong>خطا</strong>:';
            echo $error . '<br/>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    } elseif (count($reg_errors->get_error_messages()) < 1) {
        $post_data = array(
          'post_title'    => $tourTitle,
          'post_content'  => $tourContent,
          'post_status'   => 'pending',
          'post_author'   => get_current_user_id(),
        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="margin-top: 10px;font-size:15px;">تور مسافرتی با موفقیت ثبت شد. پس از بررسی مدیریت و تایید منتشر خواهد شد.</div>';
    }     
}
?>
```